# Is there a way to include aws cognito identity ID for S3 lambda filter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a lambda trigger in S3.

I'm using Amplify framework and it has an opinionated S3 folder structures for users.

Context:

I'm building a website where user can upload their files. e.g.

- `/protected/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/profile_pictures`
- `/protected/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/birthdays`
- `/protected/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/[some-other-subfolders]`

I want to trigger lambda for each section `profile_pictures`, `birthdays`, etc.

I found the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering) regarding prefix and suffix filtering for S3 and lambda.

However, they say we can't use * (wildcard) for the prefix / suffix rules.

So the question is, is there a way to generate triggers for each section (subfolders) for all users?

Ideally, if aws allows wildcard, the rule will be like:

prefix: `/protected/*/profile_picture/`

Comment: I'd put a Lambda API endpoint in front of this, so the Lambda get the data, writes it to S3 and then fires off a SNS to do "other" stuff.

Comment: @MrkFldig So, browser -> Lambda -> S3 + SNS? But lambda has limitations in the uploading size.. that's why I want to upload straight to S3.

Comment: Ahh OK so the files you're uploading are large? How big?

Comment: @MrkFldig it varies.. but I think lambda's limit is easy to hit because I know we allow videos to be uploaded

Comment: Ahh ok you're deploying via amplify is that right? With serverless it's easy but I can always knock you up a post deploy bash script to add directory trees to notifications.

Comment: OR have a staging bucket where everything goes in the root but with meta.json with it, that fires a lambda which then moves the file to right bucket and directory depending on what it says in meta.json

Comment: @MrkFldig I'm deploying the backend with serverless. I only use amplify in the frontend (because it's easy to manage aws access tokens with it). For your meta.json solution, would that mean I need to upload 2 items each time? Thanks btw!

Comment: No worries, give me half hour and I'll knock up a sample, I'm sure I've done this somewhere before!

Comment: You know what is an easier way, just fire an SNS off using your cognito identity when the file upload has completed

Comment: OR You have an array of files in your Amplify/GraphQL backend, you then have a subscription to mutations on that array that fires when you successfully upload a file and create a mutation to update the db - thats possibly better because if you do a file upload, lose connection and try and fire off an SNS, the backend won't happen, however Amplify I believe runs mutations once it gets back online.

Comment: @MrkFldig it seems there's no simple way to achieve it.. Thanks for your suggestions! We need to decide on the most practical way for now.. But your suggestions seem valid! You can compile them into an answer and I'll mark it as an answer for now!

Comment: Yeah sure will do it in the next 24 hours with a few options!